# chart.js how do we extract clicked var?

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js

I have a flask app that utilizes chart.js,

live app can viewed here: https://flaskapp.gullp.repl.co/

I'm trying to pull the clicked value from the chart and put it into a variable that resides outside of the chart function.

Here is my chart logic:

```
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
              labels: /* {{ labels }}*/ ['Big Home', 'Medium Home', 'Small Home'] ,
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'count per label',
                  data: /*{{ values }} */ [3,2,1]
              }]
          },
          options: {
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true
                      }
                  }]
              }
              //below allows you to click the chart and get the respective value. you will pass this value to python
                ,onClick: function(c,i) {
      
                e = i[0];
                //console.log(e._index)
                var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];
                var y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
               // console.log(x_value);
                //console.log(y_value);
                console.log('you clicked the graph, now the x value is = ' + x_value)
                console.log('since you clicked, this is the chart clicked data = ' + JSON.stringify(chart_clicked_data) )
        
                document.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((tr, i) => {
                  if(i === 0){
                    // skip column names 
                    return
                  }
                  if(tr.children[0].innerText != x_value){
                    tr.style.display = 'none';
                  }else {
                    tr.style.display = 'table-row';
                  }
                })
              } 
          }
      });
```

Here is my code trying to extract the x-value:

```
var chart_clicked_data = { 'score' : myChart.options.x_value}
      console.log('this is the json chart clicked data that we want to pass back to flask = ' + JSON.stringify(chart_clicked_data) )
```

seems like this is not doing the trick:

```
myChart.config.options.x_value
```

when i check the console after i click the value, its not showing to be picking up.

[image]

entire live code here:
https://repl.it/join/rbkobiqi-gullp

Answer (score 0):

Add an variable outside of your chartFunctions, set that variable in the click handler and then use it

```js
let xVal = ''

var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: function(c, i) {

      e = i[0];
      //console.log(e._index)
      var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];
      var y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
      // console.log(x_value);
      //console.log(y_value);
      console.log('you clicked the graph, now the x value is = ' + x_value)
      xVal = x_value
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('temp').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('X val: ', xVal);
  alert('X val: ' + xVal)
})

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <button id="temp">
    show pressed X value
    </button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```